# Time series data in long format, coalesce specific rows timepoints while ignoring others for each participant

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm looking for a -preferably tidy- solution for the following. I have longitudinal data from 4 timepoints in the long format and occasionally my variables of interest (`var1`, `var2`,...) have missing values at various times. I'm looking for a way to coalesce values for `t1` and `t2` rows only for each `id` under the following conditions:

- For cols that start with `var`, if there are `NA`s at `t1`, use their corresponding values from `t2`.
- Similarly, if there are missing value at `t2`, try filling them with `t1` values.
- If both are `NA`, then leave them as `NA`.
- If there are different values at `t1` and `t2`, leave them as they are.
- Ignore `t3` and `t4s` values all together

I think I'm on the right track with a combination of `group_by`, `starts_with` and `summarise` functions but I can't get the exact desired output. A couple of other threads here were similar but didn't fulfill the specific timepoints criteria that ignores the other times.

example data:

```
df1
# A tibble: 16 x 4
   id    time   var1  var2
   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A1    t1       NA    NA
 2 A1    t2        2     3
 3 A1    t3        2     2
 4 A1    t4        3     2
 5 A2    t1        1     2
 6 A2    t2       NA    NA
 7 A2    t3        2    NA
 8 A2    t4        1     2
 9 A3    t1        2     3
10 A3    t2       NA     1
11 A3    t3       NA    NA
12 A3    t4        2     2
13 A4    t1       NA    NA
14 A4    t2       NA     1
15 A4    t3        1     1
16 A4    t4        1     1
```

desired output

```
df2
# A tibble: 16 x 4
   id    time   var1  var2
   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A1    t1        2     3
 2 A1    t2        2     3
 3 A1    t3        2     2
 4 A1    t4        3     2
 5 A2    t1        1     2
 6 A2    t2        1     2
 7 A2    t3        2    NA
 8 A2    t4        1     2
 9 A3    t1        2     3
10 A3    t2        2     1
11 A3    t3       NA    NA
12 A3    t4        2     2
13 A4    t1       NA     1
14 A4    t2       NA     1
15 A4    t3        1     1
16 A4    t4        1     1
```

reprex datasets:

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", 
"A2", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A4", "A4", "A4", "A4"), time = c("t1", 
"t2", "t3", "t4", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", 
"t1", "t2", "t3", "t4"), var1 = c(NA, 2, 2, 3, 1, NA, 2, 1, 2, 
NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 1, 1), var2 = c(NA, 3, 2, 2, 2, NA, NA, 2, 
3, 1, NA, 2, NA, 1, 1, 1)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -16L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), time = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), var1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), var2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))

df2 <- structure(list(id = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", 
"A2", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A4", "A4", "A4", "A4"), time = c("t1", 
"t2", "t3", "t4", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", 
"t1", "t2", "t3", "t4"), var1 = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
2, NA, 2, NA, NA, 1, 1), var2 = c(3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, NA, 2, 3, 
1, NA, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -16L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), time = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), var1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), var2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can split out t1 and t2 and use `tidyr::fill(... .direction = "updown")` to create the logic you want for those, then bind that to the t3 and t4 values, and resort.

```
bind_rows(
  df1 %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    filter(time %in% c("t1", "t2")) %>%
    fill(c("var1", "var2"), .direction = "updown"),
  df1 %>%
    filter(time %in% c("t3", "t4"))
  ) %>%
  arrange(id, time) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 16 x 4
   id    time   var1  var2
   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A1    t1        2     3
 2 A1    t2        2     3
 3 A1    t3        2     2
 4 A1    t4        3     2
 5 A2    t1        1     2
 6 A2    t2        1     2
 7 A2    t3        2    NA
 8 A2    t4        1     2
 9 A3    t1        2     3
10 A3    t2        2     1
11 A3    t3       NA    NA
12 A3    t4        2     2
13 A4    t1       NA     1
14 A4    t2       NA     1
15 A4    t3        1     1
16 A4    t4        1     1
```

Comment: Fantastic! I don't know how I didn't know about the `fill` function, that makes life so much easier. Thank you very much